# Function doesnt return a value

Tags: php, function

I'm very new to PHP, so I'm probably missing something very obvious here, but I just can't figure it out.

```
function get_halfway_index($position, $size) {
  for($i = 0; $i < ($size / 2); $i++){
    if ($position == $size){
      $position = 0;
    } else {
      $position++;
    }
  }
  echo "returning " . $position . "<br>";
  return $potition;
}
echo "value returned: " . get_halfway_index(0, 500) . "<br>";
```

I have a function, `get_halfway_index`, that does some stuff and is supposed to return `$potition` at the end. I print the value before returning it, and it prints the right value- so no problem there. But when I try calling the function, nothing gets returned.

The output is

```
returning 250
value returned:
```

Comment: `potition` ?...

Comment: @Fast Snail ...oh. I spent the past hour or so confused about this, trying to find some syntax error when I just can't spell apparently. Awkward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo

```
return $potition
```

should be

```
return $position
```

Comment: ..well that's embarrassing. I thought I was going crazy there.

Comment: @hhaslam11 did php did not show error?

Comment: @imox nope. Not sure why, though.

Comment: @hhaslam11 you must have your error reporting suppressed. Remember to     start error reporting in such condition. You can also use phpfiddle.org to test php code block such as yours. I saw the error there instantly. :-)

Comment: Yes. You can enable error and warning reporting. Look at this question: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings

Comment: @imox Ahh, yeah- error reporting was off for some reason. I just assumed it was always on, I didn't actually think you could disable/enable error reporting. Like I said, I'm extremely new to PHP, so this is all pretty foreign to me. Thanks though, that'll definitely help in the future.

Answer (score 1):

you have a spelling error potition instead of position

```
function get_halfway_index($position, $size) {
  for($i = 0; $i < ($size / 2); $i++){
    if ($position == $size){
      $position = 0;
    } else {
      $position++;
    }
  }
  echo "returning " . $position . "<br>";
  return $position;
}
echo "value returned: " . get_halfway_index(0, 500) . "<br>";
```